# Error in Django email validation in model forms(signup)

Tags: django

I am trying to validate the email of the signup form if the user with that email already exists it should show an error like email already exists but I am not able to achieve this with the below code

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from . models import signup

class signupForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    confirm_password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = signup
        fields = ['username', 'email' , 'password','confirm_password']
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super(signupForm, self).clean()
        password = cleaned_data.get("password")
        confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")


        if password != confirm_password:
            raise forms.ValidationError(
                "password and confirm_password does not match"
            )    
        email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
        try:
            match = signup.objects.get(email=email)
            print(match)
        except signup.DoesNotExist:
            # Unable to find a user, this is fine
            return email

        # A user was found with this as a username, raise an error.
        raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.')
class loginForm(ModelForm):
    password = forms.CharField(widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    class Meta:
        model = signup
        fields = ['email','password']
```

it is showing AttributeError at /signup
'str' object has no attribute 'get' this error

Answer (score 0):

You're returning the email string from the clean method if there is no match. But the main `clean` method should return the entire cleaned_data dict, not an individual field.

In any case though, that part of the validation logic should go in the specific `clean_email` method, which *does* need to return the email string. So you would have:

```
def clean_email(self):
    email = self.cleaned_data.get('email')
    try:
        match = signup.objects.get(email=email)
        print(match)
    except signup.DoesNotExist:
        # Unable to find a user, this is fine
        return email

    # A user was found with this as a username, raise an error.
    raise forms.ValidationError('This email address is already in use.')

def clean(self):
    cleaned_data = super(signupForm, self).clean()
    password = cleaned_data.get("password")
    confirm_password = cleaned_data.get("confirm_password")


    if password != confirm_password:
        raise forms.ValidationError(
            "password and confirm_password does not match"
        )
    return cleaned_data
```

(And note, nothing to do with this question but your login form should not be a ModelForm; that will lead to other validation issues.)